# Getting a rails 4 app with omniauth / facebook oauth authentication to work with IOS app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth

I have a rails app setup with omniauth and 2 providers, facebook & strava (using 'omniauth-facebook' and 'omniauth-strava' gems).

I've just created an api for my app and am trying to get this working with oauth logins as well, but I'm not sure where to start.

I've seen a couple of old solutions online for just facebook using graph api. Would anyone know the best way to approach this in my case with the above 2 providers?